# How to select and print some columns for all the rows that are not NA and are a specifc number in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am having trouble selecting the rowns I want and printing the colums of choice.

So I have 8 columns and what I am looking to do is take all the rows where column 8 is not NA and is equal to 2, and print only columns 2 to 5.

I have tried this:

```
df.where(df['dhch'].notnull())[['scchdg', 'dhch']]
```

Here I have just entered 2 columns to check that the conditional statement that dhch is not NA worked and I got as expected:

```
       scchdg  dhch
0           3     1
1          -1     2
2          -1     2
3           1     1
4           3     1
      ...   ...
12094      -9     1
12095       1     1
12096       4     1
12097       3     1
12098       4     1

[12099 rows x 2 columns]
```

And when I check the conditional value I get expected output (i.e., values of 2 and nans in the dhch col:

```
df.where(df['dhch']==2)[['scchdg', 'dhch']]
Out[50]: 
       scchdg  dhch
0         NaN   NaN
1        -1.0   2.0
2        -1.0   2.0
3         NaN   NaN
4         NaN   NaN
      ...   ...
12094     NaN   NaN
12095     NaN   NaN
12096     NaN   NaN
12097     NaN   NaN
12098     NaN   NaN

[12099 rows x 2 columns]
```

But When I combine these, I just get piles of NAs

```
df.where(df['dhch'].notnull() & df['dhch']==2)[['scchdg', 'dhch']]
Out[51]: 
       scchdg  dhch
0         NaN   NaN
1         NaN   NaN
2         NaN   NaN
3         NaN   NaN
4         NaN   NaN
      ...   ...
12094     NaN   NaN
12095     NaN   NaN
12096     NaN   NaN
12097     NaN   NaN
12098     NaN   NaN

[12099 rows x 2 columns]
```

What am I doing wrong please?

in R what I want to do is as follows:

```
df[!is.na(df$dhch) & df$dhch==2, c('scchdg', 'dhch')]
```

But how do i do exactly this in Python please?

Comment: You should review what [DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where) does. Where: "Replace[s] values where the condition is False." IIUC something like `df.loc[df['dhch'] == 2, ['scchdg', 'dhch']]` to get the 2 columns 'scchdg', 'dhch' where 'dhch' is 2 or `df[df['dhch'] == 2]`  to get all columns where 'dhch' is 2. You don't need to check that a value is notnull and the value is 2 since `null != 2`.

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output is: first you say want to _"take all the rows where column 8 is not NA and is equal to 2"_ (so you're **filtering** some rows),  but then you  also say _"I get expected output"_ on an example where you have all the rows. Please clarify your objective.